# Python - serialising class instances with class definitions

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pickle

I'm trying to save some objects to file, which are instances of various  classes.

I've been using `pickle` for this, but have run into a problem whereby if I copy the serialised files and try to use them in a different repository, things break because the class definitions for the objects are no longer there.

When I load these objects back in to Python, I'd like them to work "out-of-the-box" — without needing the class definitions to be in exactly the right place (relative to the file in question). I was under the impression that `dill` lets you do this, but just doing `dill.dump`, `dill.load` doesn't seem to serialise the class definitions along with the objects.

Any ideas? Happy to use something other than `dill` if need be.

Thanks